# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of $\lim f(x)g(x) = \lim f(x)\lim g(x)$ for $x\to a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

Can someone please hold my hand and guide me through this proof.
I saw it in spivaks examples and yet it does not make sense!
Your help is very appreciated

Comment: What exactly "makes no sense" in that proof you read? Besides this, the formula is true **if** we assume both $\;\lim f(x)\;,\;\;\lim g(x)\;$ separatedly exist finitely...

Comment: how do you you obtain the bounds for the delta/epsilons

Comment: the min values!! and how do you obtain it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\ell'$$

and by the limit's definition we have for $\epsilon>0$ there's $\delta,\delta'>0$
$$|f(x)-\ell|<\epsilon\quad \text{if}\; |x-a|<\delta$$
and
$$|g(x)-\ell'|<\epsilon\quad \text{if}\; |x-a|<\delta'$$
and for $\delta''=\min(\delta,\delta')$ we have
$$|f(x)g(x)-\ell\ell'|=|f(x)g(x)-g(x)\ell+g(x)\ell-\ell\ell'|\le|g(x)|\cdot|f(x)-\ell|+|\ell|\cdot|g(x)-\ell'|\\\le (M+|\ell|)\epsilon \quad \text{if}\; |x-a|<\delta''$$
where $|g(x)|<M$ for $|x-a|<\delta''$ since $g$ has a limit at $a$ then it's bounded in a neighborhood of $a$. It remains for us to conclude.

Comment: You are implicitly making the assumption that $a$ is in the domain of $f$ and $g$ which is not needed.

Comment: I gave an answer in the common situation but even in the case where $a$ is in the adherence of the domain there's not a big thing to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a$ is a limit point of the domain of $f$ and $g$ which is $A\subseteq X$.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a}f(x) &= f\\
\therefore\mbox{Given }\epsilon>0 & \exists\delta_{f}>0\\
0<|x-a|<\delta_{f} &\implies |f(x)-f|<\frac{\epsilon}{2M} \qquad\mbox{Explanation Below}\\
\lim_{x\to a}g(x) &= g\\
0<|x-a|<\delta_{g} &\implies |g(x)-g|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(|f|+1)}\\
\mbox{Now, } \forall x\;s.t. &0<|x-a|<\min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}\\
|f(x)g(x)-fg| &= |f(x)g(x)-fg(x)+fg(x)-fg|\\
 &\leq |f(x)g(x)-fg(x)|+|fg(x)-fg|\\
 &= |f(x)-f|\cdot|g(x)|+|f|\cdot|g(x)-g|\\
 &< \frac{\epsilon}{2M}\cdot|g(x)|+|f|\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2(|f|+1)}\\
 &< \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon\\
 \end{align}

Explanation for M
 : Because $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$
  exists, If $(x_{n})$
  is a sequence converging to $a$ in $A\setminus a$
 , $g(x_{n})$
  converges to $g$
 . Convergent sequences are bounded. Hence, $|g(x)|<M$
 .

Comment: Indeed we can use sequences to prove this statement. Also I think that is not necessary to assume that $a$ is a limit point it sufficient that $a$ be adherent.

Comment: @Nitish Only assuming that $a$ is a limit point of $dom f$ and $dom g$ is WRONG. In fact, $a$ must be a limit point of $dom (f*g)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $f$ and $g$ are continuous at the point $x=a$, we have that

$|f(x)g(x) - f(a)g(a)| \leq |f(x)g(x) - f(a)g(x) + f(a)g(x) - f(a)g(a)|$
$\leq |g(x)||f(x) - f(a)| + |f(x)||g(x) - g(a)|$

Now since $f,g$ are continuous at $x=a$, the function $f,g$ are bounded in a neighborhood about $x=a$, call this bound $M$.  Moreover, given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(a)|, |g(x) - g(a)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$ when $|x-a| < \delta$.  Hence, using the inequalities above, we get that $|f(x)g(x) - f(a)g(a)| \leq 2M(\frac{\epsilon}{2M}) \leq \epsilon$ as when $|x-a| < \delta$, as needed.

Comment: I think, in this particular case is not necessary to assume that $f$ and $g$ are continuous just that $a$ is adherent to the domain of $f,g$ and the limit of each one exist.

Comment: @ Jose, I agree.  The continuity assumption is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

(Partial Answer) Since
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to a}g(x)=m$$

we have

(1) For any $\epsilon_f>0$, there exists $\delta_f > 0$ such that for any x, if $0<|x-a|<\delta_f,\quad$ then

$$\quad|f(x)-l| < \epsilon_f
\quad\implies \quad |f(x) - l| \cdot |g(x)| < \epsilon_f\cdot|g(x)|
\quad 
\\ \quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
\implies \quad |f(x)g(x) - lg(x)| < \epsilon_f |g(x)| $$

(2) For any $\epsilon_g > 0$ there exists $\delta_g > 0$ such that for any x, if $0<|x-c|<\delta_g,\quad$ then    $$ \\ \quad|g(x)-m| < \epsilon_g
\quad\implies\quad |g(x)-m| \cdot |l| < \epsilon_g \cdot |l| \\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
\implies\quad |lg(x)-lm| < \epsilon_g |l| \\  \text{and} ^{(*)} \\
|g(x) - m|< \epsilon_g\quad\implies\quad   g(x)<\epsilon_g + m \\$$

Now assuming $\epsilon>0$, and choosing $\epsilon_g=\epsilon_f=\epsilon$  and  letting $\delta = \min(\delta_f, \delta_g)$, we can derive that for any x, if
$0<|x-a| < \delta$, then
$$\quad\ |f(x)g(x) - lg(x)| < \epsilon |g(x)| \quad \text{and}\quad
|lg(x) - lm| < \epsilon |l|$$
by adding the two together we arrive to
$$ \epsilon |g(x)| + \epsilon |l| \quad \gt \quad |f(x)g(x) - lg(x)| + |lg(x) - lm| \\\geq \quad |f(x)g(x) - lm|$$
by (*) we get,
$$\epsilon |\epsilon + m| + \epsilon |l| \quad \gt \quad |f(x)g(x) - lm|
$$

Notice, we can get to the value strictly less than $\epsilon$, by choosing the appropriate values for $\epsilon_f$ and $\epsilon_g$, I will update the answer once I find the fitting values for $\epsilon_f$ and $\epsilon_g$.